# Can't make div scrollable using Tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I want #projects div to take rest of the aviable space and be scrollable when there is too much items

https://codepen.io/snqqmzel-the-scripter/pen/RwEGRjz

I tried to set some height, but this is not helped

The [layout](https://tailwindui.com/img/component-images/dark-project-app-screenshot.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  <title>tipt</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="grid grid-cols-12 h-screen overflow-hidden">
    <div class="col-span-3 h-full bg-black"></div>
    <div class="col-span-9 h-full flex flex-col">
      <header class="h-16 w-full bg-blue-500"></header>
      <main class="flex-1 w-full">
        <div class="grid h-full grid-cols-12">
          <div class="bg-gray-500 text-gray-50 p-8 col-span-8">
            <div class="flex items-center justify-between mb-8 p-0">
              <span>All projects</span>
            </div>
            <div id="projects" class="flex flex-col gap-5 overflow-y-auto h-[calc(100vh - 16rem)]">
              <div class="project h-[60px] bg-red-500"></div>
              <div class="project h-[60px] bg-red-500"></div>
              <div class="project h-[60px] bg-red-500"></div>
              <div class="project h-[60px] bg-red-500"></div>
              <div class="project h-[60px] bg-red-500"></div>
              <div class="project h-[60px] bg-red-500"></div>
              <div class="project h-[60px] bg-red-500"></div>
              <div class="project h-[60px] bg-red-500"></div>
              <div class="project h-[60px] bg-red-500"></div>
              <div class="project h-[60px] bg-red-500"></div>
              <div class="project h-[60px] bg-red-500"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <aside class="col-span-4 bg-green-500"></aside>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `height: 100%` from the `<div>` that wraps the right side elements. This will stop "shrinking" from being able to happen inside it. In some inner elements, apply `min-height: 0` via `min-h-0` to override the default `min-height: min-content`, so that some elements can shrink shorter in height than their content (as would be the case for a long list of `.projects`. Make the `bg-gray-500` container a vertical flex container so that the `#projects` container can grow or shrink and overflow its content.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<div class="grid grid-cols-12 h-screen overflow-hidden">
  <div class="col-span-3 h-full bg-black"></div>
  <div class="col-span-9 flex flex-col min-h-0">
    <header class="h-16 w-full bg-blue-500"></header>
    <main class="flex-1 w-full min-h-0">
      <div class="grid h-full grid-cols-12">
        <div class="flex flex-col bg-gray-500 text-gray-50 p-8 col-span-8 min-h-0">
          <div class="flex items-center justify-between mb-8 p-0">
            <span>All projects</span>
          </div>
          <div id="projects" class="flex flex-col gap-5 overflow-y-auto grow">
            <div class="project h-[60px] bg-red-500 flex-shrink-0"></div>
            <div class="project h-[60px] bg-red-500 flex-shrink-0"></div>
            <div class="project h-[60px] bg-red-500 flex-shrink-0"></div>
            <div class="project h-[60px] bg-red-500 flex-shrink-0"></div>
            <div class="project h-[60px] bg-red-500 flex-shrink-0"></div>
            <div class="project h-[60px] bg-red-500 flex-shrink-0"></div>
            <div class="project h-[60px] bg-red-500 flex-shrink-0"></div>
            <div class="project h-[60px] bg-red-500 flex-shrink-0"></div>
            <div class="project h-[60px] bg-red-500 flex-shrink-0"></div>
            <div class="project h-[60px] bg-red-500 flex-shrink-0"></div>
            <div class="project h-[60px] bg-red-500 flex-shrink-0"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <aside class="col-span-4 bg-green-500"></aside>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

As an aside, `h-[calc(100vh - 16rem)]` is an invalid CSS class. Since space characters are used to delimit class names, you'd need to escape spaces in arbitrary values with underscores (`_`): `h-[calc(100vh_-_16rem)]`. Furthermore, Tailwind will automatically "normalize" `calc()` expressions in arbitrary classes so you could actually do `h-[calc(100vh-16rem)]`.